# ARCoachingOverlayView doesnt start immediately in AR app

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have an AR app in iOS using ARKit I am initialising the ARCoachingOberlayView as below given in the code, problem is the coaching animation doesnt load immediately, it takes around 5-10 secs and then starts. I wish to either display my own animation instead till the coaching overlay loads or want to start it immediately. What changes I need ?

```
  coachingOverlay.session = sceneView.session
    coachingOverlay.delegate = self
    
    
    coachingOverlay.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sceneView.addSubview(coachingOverlay)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        coachingOverlay.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        coachingOverlay.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        coachingOverlay.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
        coachingOverlay.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor)
        ])
    
    coachingOverlay.activatesAutomatically = true
    
    coachingOverlay.goal = .verticalPlane
```

How can I make it load immediately as the camera starts .